# Module java.xml.bind not found

Tags: eclipse, javafx

I am new with `javafx` and eclipse . I installed eclipse then javafx from the eclipse market . I generated an fxml code with scene builder but I can not execute it . I m really blocked and couldnt find any soltution

I added `--add-modules java.xml.bind` as an argument in run configuration , but no chance

```
 Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.xml.bind not found
```

Comment: Which version of Java are you using to run your JavaFX application?

Answer (score 7):

This has been removed from the JDK with version 11+. You have to explicitly add some external dependencies to your project.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

And remove the `--add-modules` directive.

Comment: This gets more complicated at every turn.

Comment: Where to add this??

Comment: @Saurabh, I just searched for .xml files, and within them, for one with "<dependency>" tags.. The application did launch then but not past the splash :-) I just needed this to run a medical image viewer which comes along with Your X-ray images, but it turned out there is a package Aeskulap which can open DICOM files without trying to compile weasis :-D