# Flutter doctor not accepting android license in console

Tags: android, flutter

I decided to develop a mobile application with flutter. When I type `flutter doctor` to the console, I have to accept the Android License. This is what came up when I typed flutter doctor `flutter doctor --android-licenses`. Could You Help?

Error:

[image]

Comment: Check this question, probably it's related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68210100/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-annotation-xmlschema-when-accep

Answer (score 1):

I got this same problem when I installed flutter again

Open Android Studio and go to SDK Manager and click SDK Tools

And download tools shown in this picture

[SDK Tools for Android Licenses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2ckr.jpg)

Restart your pc and run 'flutter run-v' in cmd or terminal